# will data-position="fixed" work for divs other than header and footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've a div(phone-no) which need to be fixed and it is just above the footer. When we resize the window, user must be able to see the "phone-no" div. here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Ppt.jpg) the blue bar which says "free trial" is the fixed bar and the bar below that is the footer.

When I tried data-position="fixed' on header and footer, it seems to work. but not on this. Any insight?? [link to the page](http://move.clanteam.com/testing-fixed-position.html)

Comment: What about adding the HTML structure of your DIV as a child of the `data-role="footer"` element and then giving it CSS like this: `position : absolute; top : -20px; height : 20px;` This will keep the element just above the footer at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zD5RU/4/
- http://jsfiddle.net/zD5RU/8/ (more content)

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h1>Header</h1> 
        <a href="#" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> 
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed"> 
        <div data-role="navbar"> 
            <ul> 
                <li></li> 
                <li></li>
                <li>Footer</li>
                <li></li> 
                <li>(888)444-8901</li> 
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Problem is I've a separate footer. This phone no can't be writen on the footer

Answer (score 3):

Try put this code in your document ready and it will disable disappearing when clicking and scrolling

```
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

Best of luck